# ReactJS with Python as Backend

Tags: python, reactjs, django

What is the best approach to use ReactJS as front end and Python as a backend? I already built a tool using Tkinter which have simple UI. I want to use ReactJS and rebuild this application that anyone can install on their desktops. Is it possible? If so can anyone briefly explain the workflow or any online resources would be appreciated. Thank you! (I have a basic knowledge using Djnago)

Comment: React is a *frontend* framework meant for building javascript applications that all modern browsers can parse.  Since you already built your UI with `Tkinter`, and your making a *desktop application* rather than a website, I would recommend sticking with `Tkinter`.

Comment: That being said, this question is off-topic, and will likely be closed soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a great idea in the modern world of web technology, using ReactJS as a frontend and Django Rest Framework to make your API, and Django for the backend aspect is a great choice as you could utilize the API in other application such as a mobile application.

I would suggest you go with those technologies as most big and medium scale websites now uses ReactJs with Django/Django Rest Framework or some other backend tools.

If you have any other question, i would be glad to answer it.

Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. If I build using these technologies, is it possible to convert this to a desktop application?

Comment: Django is a web framework. If you're switching to a desktop, you'll have to forego Django.

Comment: I would try to replicate the Django application functionality with the PyQt toolkit.
You can in fact embed web content in PyQt applications, with the help of QtWebKit. I would post some potentially useful links, but apparently I have too low a reputation to post more than one

Answer (score -1):

Sure, people have used React for their desktop applications. Slack for example have used React in there desktop applications so you are in good company there ;)

https://slack.engineering/rebuilding-slack-on-the-desktop/

But why not just put your UI in a simple web application with React and avoid the hassle to support multiple operating systems and versions?